# This may be very simple but how come this code <%= @user.name %> doesn't work on all pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the following error after putting it on certain pages in Ruby on Rails:

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

It also says there is no method error in the page I am on. I know this may be a beginner question but it has been stumping me big time in my project. If you can give me some advice I'd be very happy! Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Apparently `@user` is not defined (_is `nil`_) on those pages producing error. Change the code to `<%= @user.nil? ? 'NOT DEFINED' : @user.name %>` and see it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all: It's a common trap. We all fall into it from time to time.

When ever you read `undefined method foobar for nil:NilClass` you know that something is `nil` what shouldn't be `nil`. So you have to check why `@user` is `nil`. Maybe a bug in the controller.

**If** you want to handle both situations (`nil` AND `User`) than you can use this code:

```
<%= @user.name if @user %>
```

Comment: or simply `@user.try(:name)`

Comment: You honestly were all so helpful, I have fixed the issue! Everyone that commented and posted the answer has helped me, I even wrote it down as a note so I don't forget! haha Thanks guys!

Comment: '.try()' often opens the door for future bugs. It's a lazy solution.

Comment: If an answer is correct: Accept it by clicking on the little check mark below the up and down vote link.

Comment: @wintermeyer  `@user.try(:name)` works **exact** same as `@user.name if @user`. I don't see any reasons to choose latest.

Comment: @Rustam Actually there is a difference - `@user.try(:name)` would suppress a no method error if `@user` was a non-nil object with no :name method